# What SELinux setting is preventing Samba from displaying and allowing me access to shares?

Tags: fedora, samba, selinux, smb

I have a very basic `/etc/samba/smb.conf` configuration:

```
[global]
        workgroup = WORKGROUP
        server string = Samba server (%v) on %h

        security = user
        passdb backend = tdbsam
[data]
        comment = Share
        path = /data
        writable = yes
        valid users = jim fred
```

I have configured the share directory with the appropriate SELinux context permissions and issued `restorecon`:

```
# semanage fcontext -a -t samba_share_t "/data(/.*)?"
# restorecon -R /data
```

I have enabled the following SELinux boolean options for Samba:

```
# setsebool -P samba_enable_home_dirs on
# setsebool -P samba_export_all_rw on
# getsebool -a | grep samba
samba_create_home_dirs --> off
samba_domain_controller --> off
samba_enable_home_dirs --> on
samba_export_all_ro --> off
samba_export_all_rw --> on
samba_load_libgfapi --> off
samba_portmapper --> off
samba_run_unconfined --> off
samba_share_fusefs --> off
samba_share_nfs --> off
sanlock_use_samba --> off
tmpreaper_use_samba --> off
use_samba_home_dirs --> off
virt_use_samba --> off
```

I have created a Samba user account for user `jim`:

```
# smbpasswd -a jim
```

I can verify the Samba user:

```
# pdbedit -L -v
---------------
Unix username:        jim
NT username:
Account Flags:        [U          ]
User SID:             S-1-5-21-1313117023-1808504127-2290582315-1001
Primary Group SID:    S-1-5-21-1313117023-1808504127-2290582315-513
Full Name:            The Jim of Legend
Home Directory:       \\LSERVER\jim
HomeDir Drive:
Logon Script:
Profile Path:         \\LSERVERS\jim\profile
Domain:               LSERVER
Account desc:
Workstations:
Munged dial:
Logon time:           0
Logoff time:          Wed, 06 Feb 2036 10:06:39 EST
Kickoff time:         Wed, 06 Feb 2036 10:06:39 EST
Password last set:    Tue, 16 Aug 2022 18:02:06 EDT
Password can change:  Tue, 16 Aug 2022 18:02:06 EDT
Password must change: never
Last bad password   : 0
Bad password count  : 0
Logon hours         : FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

I have restarted smb and nmb after setting up the configuration:

```
service smb restart && service nmb restart
```

The smb service starts up fine:

```
# service smb status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status smb.service
● smb.service - Samba SMB Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/smb.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2022-08-16 17:56:22 EDT; 7s ago
       Docs: man:smbd(8)
             man:samba(7)
             man:smb.conf(5)
   Main PID: 2795706 (smbd)
     Status: "smbd: ready to serve connections..."
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 76912)
     Memory: 5.6M
        CPU: 47ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/smb.service
             ├─ 2795706 /usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group
             ├─ 2795708 /usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group
             └─ 2795709 /usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group

Aug 16 17:56:22 lserver systemd[1]: Starting smb.service - Samba SMB Daemon...
Aug 16 17:56:22 lserver smbd[2795706]: [2022/08/16 17:56:22.850039,  0] ../../source3/smbd/server.c:1741(main)
Aug 16 17:56:22 lserver smbd[2795706]:   smbd version 4.16.4 started.
Aug 16 17:56:22 lserver smbd[2795706]:   Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2022
Aug 16 17:56:22 lserver systemd[1]: Started smb.service - Samba SMB Daemon.
```

But, when I try to list what shares are available to `jim`, none are available:

```
# smbclient -L localhost -U jim
Password for [WORKGROUP\jim]:

        Sharename       Type      Comment
        ---------       ----      -------
```

`service smb status` reports a number of errors in the log:

```
# service smb status
...
Aug 16 18:04:27 lserver samba-dcerpcd[2821072]: [2022/08/16 18:04:27.828139,  0] ../../source3/rpc_server/rpc_sock_helper.c:91(dcesrv_create_ncacn_np_socket)
Aug 16 18:04:27 lserver samba-dcerpcd[2821072]:   dcesrv_create_ncacn_np_socket: Failed to create ncacn_np socket! '/run/samba/ncalrpc/np/spoolss': Address already in use
Aug 16 18:04:27 lserver samba-dcerpcd[2821072]: [2022/08/16 18:04:27.828218,  0] ../../source3/lib/util_sock.c:977(create_pipe_sock)
Aug 16 18:04:27 lserver samba-dcerpcd[2821072]:   bind failed on pipe socket /run/samba/ncalrpc/np/srvsvc: Address already in use
Aug 16 18:04:27 lserver samba-dcerpcd[2821072]: [2022/08/16 18:04:27.828242,  0] ../../source3/rpc_server/rpc_sock_helper.c:91(dcesrv_create_ncacn_np_socket)
Aug 16 18:04:27 lserver samba-dcerpcd[2821072]:   dcesrv_create_ncacn_np_socket: Failed to create ncacn_np socket! '/run/samba/ncalrpc/np/srvsvc': Address already in use
Aug 16 18:04:27 lserver samba-dcerpcd[2821072]: [2022/08/16 18:04:27.828740,  0] ../../source3/lib/util_sock.c:977(create_pipe_sock)
Aug 16 18:04:27 lserver samba-dcerpcd[2821072]:   bind failed on pipe socket /run/samba/ncalrpc/np/winreg: Address already in use
Aug 16 18:04:27 lserver samba-dcerpcd[2821072]: [2022/08/16 18:04:27.828763,  0] ../../source3/rpc_server/rpc_sock_helper.c:91(dcesrv_create_ncacn_np_socket)
Aug 16 18:04:27 lserver samba-dcerpcd[2821072]:   dcesrv_create_ncacn_np_socket: Failed to create ncacn_np socket! '/run/samba/ncalrpc/np/winreg': Address already in use
```

Here is the full log from `/var/log/messages` at the time of event:

```
2022-08-16T18:23:00.514283-04:00 lserver setroubleshoot[2878314]: SELinux is preventing samba-dcerpcd from unlink access on the sock_file rpcecho. For complete SELinux messages run: sealert -l df6a7f6a-2540-4247-91e7-4755ff529d58
2022-08-16T18:23:00.515763-04:00 lserver setroubleshoot[2878314]: SELinux is preventing samba-dcerpcd from unlink access on the sock_file rpcecho.#012#012*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************#012#012If you believe that samba-dcerpcd should be allowed unlink access on the rpcecho sock_file by default.#012Then you should report this as a bug.#012You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.#012Do#012allow this access for now by executing:#012# ausearch -c 'samba-dcerpcd' --raw | audit2allow -M my-sambadcerpcd#012# semodule -X 300 -i my-sambadcerpcd.pp#012
2022-08-16T18:23:00.518242-04:00 lserver setroubleshoot[2878314]: SELinux is preventing samba-dcerpcd from unlink access on the sock_file epmapper. For complete SELinux messages run: sealert -l df6a7f6a-2540-4247-91e7-4755ff529d58
2022-08-16T18:23:00.519194-04:00 lserver setroubleshoot[2878314]: SELinux is preventing samba-dcerpcd from unlink access on the sock_file epmapper.#012#012*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************#012#012If you believe that samba-dcerpcd should be allowed unlink access on the epmapper sock_file by default.#012Then you should report this as a bug.#012You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.#012Do#012allow this access for now by executing:#012# ausearch -c 'samba-dcerpcd' --raw | audit2allow -M my-sambadcerpcd#012# semodule -X 300 -i my-sambadcerpcd.pp#012
2022-08-16T18:23:00.521350-04:00 lserver setroubleshoot[2878314]: SELinux is preventing samba-dcerpcd from unlink access on the sock_file winreg. For complete SELinux messages run: sealert -l df6a7f6a-2540-4247-91e7-4755ff529d58
2022-08-16T18:23:00.522205-04:00 lserver setroubleshoot[2878314]: SELinux is preventing samba-dcerpcd from unlink access on the sock_file winreg.#012#012*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************#012#012If you believe that samba-dcerpcd should be allowed unlink access on the winreg sock_file by default.#012Then you should report this as a bug.#012You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.#012Do#012allow this access for now by executing:#012# ausearch -c 'samba-dcerpcd' --raw | audit2allow -M my-sambadcerpcd#012# semodule -X 300 -i my-sambadcerpcd.pp#012
2022-08-16T18:23:00.524343-04:00 lserver setroubleshoot[2878314]: SELinux is preventing samba-dcerpcd from unlink access on the sock_file lsarpc. For complete SELinux messages run: sealert -l df6a7f6a-2540-4247-91e7-4755ff529d58
2022-08-16T18:23:00.525202-04:00 lserver setroubleshoot[2878314]: SELinux is preventing samba-dcerpcd from unlink access on the sock_file lsarpc.#012#012*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************#012#012If you believe that samba-dcerpcd should be allowed unlink access on the lsarpc sock_file by default.#012Then you should report this as a bug.#012You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.#012Do#012allow this access for now by executing:#012# ausearch -c 'samba-dcerpcd' --raw | audit2allow -M my-sambadcerpcd#012# semodule -X 300 -i my-sambadcerpcd.pp#012
2022-08-16T18:23:00.527306-04:00 lserver setroubleshoot[2878314]: SELinux is preventing samba-dcerpcd from unlink access on the sock_file fssagentrpc. For complete SELinux messages run: sealert -l df6a7f6a-2540-4247-91e7-4755ff529d58
2022-08-16T18:23:00.528142-04:00 lserver setroubleshoot[2878314]: SELinux is preventing samba-dcerpcd from unlink access on the sock_file fssagentrpc.#012#012*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************#012#012If you believe that samba-dcerpcd should be allowed unlink access on the fssagentrpc sock_file by default.#012Then you should report this as a bug.#012You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.#012Do#012allow this access for now by executing:#012# ausearch -c 'samba-dcerpcd' --raw | audit2allow -M my-sambadcerpcd#012# semodule -X 300 -i my-sambadcerpcd.pp#012
2022-08-16T18:23:00.530259-04:00 lserver setroubleshoot[2878314]: SELinux is preventing samba-dcerpcd from unlink access on the sock_file mdssvc. For complete SELinux messages run: sealert -l df6a7f6a-2540-4247-91e7-4755ff529d58
2022-08-16T18:23:00.531103-04:00 lserver setroubleshoot[2878314]: SELinux is preventing samba-dcerpcd from unlink access on the sock_file mdssvc.#012#012*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************#012#012If you believe that samba-dcerpcd should be allowed unlink access on the mdssvc sock_file by default.#012Then you should report this as a bug.#012You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.#012Do#012allow this access for now by executing:#012# ausearch -c 'samba-dcerpcd' --raw | audit2allow -M my-sambadcerpcd#012# semodule -X 300 -i my-sambadcerpcd.pp#012
2022-08-16T18:23:00.533234-04:00 lserver setroubleshoot[2878314]: SELinux is preventing samba-dcerpcd from unlink access on the sock_file srvsvc. For complete SELinux messages run: sealert -l df6a7f6a-2540-4247-91e7-4755ff529d58
2022-08-16T18:23:00.534081-04:00 lserver setroubleshoot[2878314]: SELinux is preventing samba-dcerpcd from unlink access on the sock_file srvsvc.#012#012*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************#012#012If you believe that samba-dcerpcd should be allowed unlink access on the srvsvc sock_file by default.#012Then you should report this as a bug.#012You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.#012Do#012allow this access for now by executing:#012# ausearch -c 'samba-dcerpcd' --raw | audit2allow -M my-sambadcerpcd#012# semodule -X 300 -i my-sambadcerpcd.pp#012
2022-08-16T18:23:00.536250-04:00 lserver setroubleshoot[2878314]: SELinux is preventing samba-dcerpcd from unlink access on the sock_file spoolss. For complete SELinux messages run: sealert -l df6a7f6a-2540-4247-91e7-4755ff529d58
2022-08-16T18:23:00.537079-04:00 lserver setroubleshoot[2878314]: SELinux is preventing samba-dcerpcd from unlink access on the sock_file spoolss.#012#012*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************#012#012If you believe that samba-dcerpcd should be allowed unlink access on the spoolss sock_file by default.#012Then you should report this as a bug.#012You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.#012Do#012allow this access for now by executing:#012# ausearch -c 'samba-dcerpcd' --raw | audit2allow -M my-sambadcerpcd#012# semodule -X 300 -i my-sambadcerpcd.pp#012
```

SELinux does offer a workaround via audit2allow, and I found an alternate reference using the same procedure [elsewhere](https://solveforum.com/forums/threads/solved-samba-4-16-interactions-with-selinux.1309856/), but trying to use the same command, exactly as provided, reports and error about an unknown switch:

```
# ausearch -c 'samba-dcerpcd' --raw | audit2allow -M my-sambadcerpcd semodule -X 300 -i my-sambadcerpcd.pp
Usage: audit2allow [options]

audit2allow: error: no such option: -X
```

I can confirm that this is an SELinux problem specifically. If I disable SELinux and restart the smb service, the shares become visible:

```
# setenforce 0
# systemctl restart smb.service
# smbclient -L localhost -U jim
Password for [WORKGROUP\jim]:

        Sharename       Type      Comment
        ---------       ----      -------
        data            Disk      Share
        IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (Samba server (4.16.4) on lserver)
```

If I re-enable SELinux and restart the smb service, I lose access to my shares again:

```
# setenforce 1
# systemctl restart smb.service
# smbclient -L localhost -U jim
Password for [WORKGROUP\jim]:

        Sharename       Type      Comment
        ---------       ----      -------
```

It's clear that SELinux is blocking my ability to browse and access shares, but I can't figure out exactly what the issue is. Why can't I access my shares with SELinux enabled?

I'm having this issue when configuring Fedora 36. I have a CentOS 7.9 server with a similar configuration (identical, from what I can tell) that does not have this issue with SELinux enforcement enabled.

These seem to be the relevant Bugzilla reports:

- https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2083504
- https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2083509
- https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2096825

Comment: Possible to add the `/var/log/messages` entries that SELinux generates at the time of a failure ?

Comment: I've updated the question with the relevant entries from the messages log.

Comment: Also similar to this BZ https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2020977

Comment: But in the BZ, -X is a parameter to semodule, not to audit2allow. It appears OP missed the newline-equivalents in logs (#012#).

Comment: I see. I didn't realize that `#012#` are meant to be newlines. Thank you.

Comment: The [link](https://solveforum.com/forums/threads/solved-samba-4-16-interactions-with-selinux.1309856/) you refer to has *two* separate commands: `ausearch ... | audit2allow -M my-sambadcerpcd` followed by `semodule -X 300 -i my-sambadcerpcd.pp`. I don't know if that will solve the problem, but it should get you over that hurdle.